# Net core 2.0 install package to new project

Tags: c#, .net-core, nuget-package

I am new in Net core 2.0.

I have made a Solution and have differents Project (console and class).

I have added an extension library reading this [post](https://www.nuget.org/packages/AspNetCore.Http.Extensions)

So, i run

`PM>  Install-Package AspNetCore.Http.Extensions -Version 1.0.0`

and now I can add `using AspNetCore.Http.Extensions;` to all my projects's files without problems.

But when I added a new Project, `using AspNetCore.Http.Extensions` it is not recognized.

I run `PM>  Install-Package AspNetCore.Http.Extensions -Version 1.0.0` again and it shows all the projects tnat has added this reference. My new Project did not appear.

I have also add

```
<PackageReference Include="System.Runtime.Serialization.Primitives" Version="4.3.0" />
```

to my Project file and then run `dotnet restore` from command, but still nothing happens.

My question is, how can I include or install `AspNetCore.Http.Extensions` to my new Project?

Comment: Does your solution file know about your new project?

Comment: I open .sln and it appears Project("{xxx}") = "INOMSupport", "INOMSupport\INOMSupport.csproj", "{CCC}"
EndProject

it is how should be appear? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I solved this running `PM>  Install-Package AspNetCore.Http.Extensions -Version 1.0.0` only to this Project. I have selected this Project name in PM Console and run it just to this Project.